# How to Retrieve the data from the server

Tags: android, widget

After the successful connection to the server(my local host),i want to retrieve the data that server sends to me. Can anyone please suggest me what should i do for this?
After receiving that data, i have to store it into an Array and then have to fetch it one by one into the dropdown list.

Thanks

Comment: getting data from a server is usually done via an http request

Comment: I known that my questions are quite silly, but let me inform you all that,i have started with Android just two weeks before. I don't even have the basic knowledge of it,and this is my learning stage.

Comment: Thanks Slayton, But i have receive a response from the server, now just i have to retrieve that data in an Array. And than have to fetch the data from that array n place it in my Spinner object

Comment: Sheetal, you are probably not going to get the response you are looking for b/c client server communication is not a trivial problem that someone can simply explain in a few lines.  There are simple implementations but those only work for some cases. You should buy a book that explains how to implement client/server communication in Android. It will be more complete then any answer you get here and will address a lot of the caveats that you will need to take into account.

Answer (score 0):

Sheetal i have not worked with any application with server,but  i retrieved data locally and then placed it in an array and showed in the spinner, this might help u

```
Cursor c = db.fetchAllReminders();
            startManagingCursor(c); 

            // Create an array to specify the fields we want (only the TITLE)
            String[] from = new String[]{DataManager.NAME}; 
            // and an array of the fields we want to bind in the view
            int[] to=new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
//         to[0]=android.R.id.text1;

             final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spins);


            // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
            final SimpleCursorAdapter reminders =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to); 
            spinner.setAdapter(reminders);
```